# Cythonize project with many folders

Tags: python, build, cython

I have a project with the following structure:

```
fempy/
     main.py
     fem/
         setup.py
         module1.pyx
         core/
              module2.pyx
```

If every `.pyd` is created in the *same folder* as its corresponding `.pyx`, I don't have to move anything around. I just run my `main.py`. But when I run the `setup.py` the directories become like this:

```
fempy/
# the same as before
     main.py
     fem/
         setup.py
         module1.pyx
         core/
              module2.pyx
# added: the same path as the external but only with the .pyd files
         fempy/ 
             fem/
                 module1.pyd
                 core/
                     module2.pyd
```

**How to change the `setup.py` to bring the `.pyd`s next to their `.pyx`s?**

Simplistic `setup.py`:

```py
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np

setup(ext_modules = cythonize([r'core/*.pyx', r'*.pyx'], annotate=True),
      include_dirs=[np.get_include()]

      )
```

Comment: Have you tried to build the project with the command `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` ? Else, I recommend to actually install (in the local user environment or in a virtual environment) the project with pip.

Comment: I run it from the cmd. Will `pip install` make the files appear in the same folder?

Comment: No, it will install them in a location that depends on your system. The local installs go to `~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/` on linux. On Windows I have no idea. In either situations, you can import those packages from a Python program. pip also has a `-e` option to install the package "locally" but I have never used it and don't know how it works with Cython extensions.

Comment: So what you are saying is install with `pip` so the project goes to `path/to/site-pagkages`. If I then import `setup.py` will my package work? (It works only when `.pyd`s are in the supposed directory, not any directory.) Or I just import my packages directly? What troubles me is that I am still developing this project, so I still need to make changes. I haven't installed one before, so I don't know how productive will that be.

Comment: import directly, as if it were a "real package", because it will be. for cython codes, you either use `build_ext --inplace` or do an actual install.

Comment: I will try it thank you!

Comment: Let me know the result, so I can provide an actual answer for reference if appropriate.